# Java Redisson Client Redis Exceptions : org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException

Tags: java, caching, redis, redisson

I'm setting up a Redis cache layer using **AWS Elasticache Redis** version **7.0.7**

I'm usign Java Redisson client version **3.16.0** and java version **1.8**

However one of the requirement is to setup a fallback mechanism to fallback to the downstream service or database method whenever there is any exception on Redis operation

Below is my Redisson client configurations

```
redissonConfig.setNettyThreads(128);
redissonConfig.useClusterServers()
        .setKeepAlive(true)
        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
        .setRetryAttempts(0)
        .setRetryInterval(0)
        .setPingConnectionInterval(10000)
        .setDnsMonitoringInterval(20000)
        .addNodeAddress(redisAddress);
RedissonClient client = Redisson.create(redissonConfig);
return client;
```

However I'm getting below intermittent exceptions on read/write and on **evict Redis operations**

1-Read write operation Exceptions:

```
exception: org.redisson.client.RedisTimeoutException: Command still hasn't been written into connection! Try to increase nettyThreads setting. Payload size in bytes: 52. Node source: NodeSource [slot=8995, addr=null, redisClient=null, redirect=null, entry=null], connection: RedisConnection@573846890 [redisClient=[addr=rediss://xxxxx:6379], channel=[id: 0x93e5c3e6, L:/:38098 - R:xxx], currentCommand=null], command: (EVAL), params: [local value = redis.call('hget', KEYS[1], ARGV[2]); if value == false then return nil; end; local t,..., 5, data, redisson__timeout__set:{data}, redisson__idle__set:{data}, redisson__map_cache__last_access__set:{data}, {data}:redisson_options, 1684331276823, PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 52, cap: 256)] after 0 retry attempts
```

2- Exceptions when **Redisson** job try to evict the cache, I’m resolving this by doing manual eviction through redis-cli

```
exception: org.redisson.client.RedisException: ERR user_script:1: bad argument #2 to 'unpack' (data string too short) script: 401d7fca9b4e9022dffaa4fd236958c2babbc2f3, on @user_script:1.. channel: [id: 0x064bccc5
```

Appreciate if you have any recommendation to prevent such issues.

Note: the fallback mechanism is working as expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing a problem involving a `RedisTimeoutException` and a solution I found was increasing the `RetryInterval` property of the config object.

The default value for this property is 1500 milliseconds, which you have set to 0 here. As per [Redisson Wiki](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/16.-FAQ), increasing this value may given Redisson a little more time before the operation fails.

As I was struggling with the problem in the past, I hope this answer provides you with a little information that will prevent such situations.